# Understanding Threading in python: How to tell `run()` to return processed data?

Tags: python, multithreading, return-value

I read up about threading in the [IBM developer sources](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/) and found the following example.

In general I understand what happens here, except for **one** important thing. The work seems to be done in the `run()` function. In this example `run()` only prints a line and signals to the queue, that the job is done.

**What if I had to return some processed data? I thought about caching it in a global variable, and to access this one later, but this seems not the right way to go.**

Any advice?

*Perhaps I should clearify:* My intuition tells me to add `return processed_data` to `run()` right after `self.queue.task_done()`, but I can't figure out where to catch that return, since it is not obvious to me where `run()` is called.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import Queue
import threading
import urllib2
import time

hosts = ["http://yahoo.com", "http://google.com", "http://amazon.com",
"http://ibm.com", "http://apple.com"]

queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    """Threaded Url Grab"""
    def __init__(self, queue):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        while True:
            #grabs host from queue
            host = self.queue.get()

            #grabs urls of hosts and prints first 1024 bytes of page
            url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
            print url.read(1024)

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

start = time.time()
def main():

    #spawn a pool of threads, and pass them queue instance 
    for i in range(5):
        t = ThreadUrl(queue)
        t.setDaemon(True)
        t.start()

    #populate queue with data   
    for host in hosts:
        queue.put(host)

    #wait on the queue until everything has been processed     
    queue.join()

main()
print "Elapsed Time: %s" % (time.time() - start)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't return a value from `run`, and in any case there is normally more than one item to process in each thread, so you don't want to return at all after processing one value (see the `while` loop in each thread).

I would either use another queue to return the results:

```
queue = Queue.Queue()
out_queue = Queue.Queue()

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #grabs host from queue
            host = self.queue.get()

            #grabs urls of hosts and saves first 1024 bytes of page
            url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
            out_queue.put(url.read(1024))

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

...

def main():
    ...
    #populate queue with data   
    for host in hosts:
        queue.put(host)

    #don't have to wait until everything has been processed if we don't want to

    for _ in range(len(hosts)):
        first_1k = out_queue.get()
        print first_1k
```

or store the result in the same queue:

```
class WorkItem(object):
    def __init__(self, host):
        self.host = host

class ThreadUrl(threading.Thread):
    ...
    def run(self):
        while True:
            #grabs host from queue
            work_item = self.queue.get()
            host = work_item.host

            #grabs urls of hosts and saves first 1024 bytes of page
            url = urllib2.urlopen(host)
            work_item.first_1k = url.read(1024)

            #signals to queue job is done
            self.queue.task_done()

...

def main():
    ...
    #populate queue with data   
    work_items = [WorkItem(host) for host in hosts]
    for item in work_items:
        queue.put(item)

    #wait on the queue until everything has been processed     
    queue.join()

    for item in work_items:
        print item.first_1k
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with using the queue method is : the order in which the threads may complete is random . Hence the queue item may not necessarily reflect the result of that specific position .
In this example , if google.com gets done before yahoo.com , then the queue has google data before yahoo data, so when retrieving it , the results are incorrect.